# SQLSTATE=42829 while compiling a pro*c code with DB2 database

Tags: compiler-errors, db2, aix, proc

I am trying to compile a .sqc file on AIX using DB2
getting sql error **SQL0511N "The FOR UPDATE clause is not allowed because the table specified by the cursor cannot be modified.SQLSTATE=42829"** while declaring a Cursor with host_variable_int on "FETCH FIRST **:host_variable_int** ROWS ONLY" but same statement is getting compiled when pass number instead of host_variable like "FETCH FIRST **40** ROWS ONLY".

**ERROR SQL Statement:**

`EXEC SQL DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT a.coulmn_names FROM   TABLE_NAME a WHERE  a.TABLE_COLUMN_1 = :host_variable AND  a.TABLE_COLUMN_2 IN ( SELECT b.coulmn_names FROM TABLE_NAME b WHERE  b.TABLE_COLUMN_1 = :host_variable AND    a.TABLE_COLUMN_3 = b.TABLE_COLUMN_3) FETCH FIRST **:host_variable_int** ROWS ONLY FOR UPDATE OF coulmn_name;`

**NON ERROR SQL STATEMENT:**

`EXEC SQL DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT a.coulmn_names FROM   TABLE_NAME a WHERE  a.TABLE_COLUMN_1 = :host_variable AND  a.TABLE_COLUMN_2 IN ( SELECT b.coulmn_names FROM TABLE_NAME b WHERE  b.TABLE_COLUMN_1 = :host_variable AND    a.TABLE_COLUMN_3 = b.TABLE_COLUMN_3) FETCH FIRST **40** ROWS ONLY FOR UPDATE OF coulmn_name;`

I am not sure what difference in the two cursor declaration statement
Does someone have any idea about this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For current versions of Db2, this is the **expected result**.  You cannot use a host-variable for the `fetch first` row count.

In Db2, the fetch-clause has this syntax for the fetch-row-count, according to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=subselect-fetch-clause).

> fetch-row-count
> An expression that specifies the maximum number of rows to retrieve. The expression must not contain a column reference, a
> scalar-fullselect, a function that is not deterministic, a function
> that has an external action, or a sequence reference (SQLSTATE 428H7).
> The numeric value must be a positive number or zero (SQLSTATE 2201W).
> If the data type of the expression is not BIGINT, the result of the
> expression is cast to a BIGINT value. When fetch-row-count is omitted,
> it is equivalent to 1.

If you want to vary the fetch first value , you have to use dynamic-SQL and you cannot use static-sql.